# Elasticsearch Updates Not Searchable

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am running a script to a container with ES in order to update the contents of an array of strings named `tags`. I am able to see the new `tag` stored within Elasticsearch, but in a separate document. I would like to have the *current* document be updated instead.

This is the `Script` that is being sent :

```java
  private String updateESTags() {
    return "if (ctx._source.containsKey(\"MyTags\")) { " +
            "                  def targets = ctx._source.MyTags.findAll(anArray -> " +
            "                    anArray.tags.contains(params.oldName) " +
            "                  ); " +
            "                  for (tagArray in targets) { " +
            "                    tagArray.tags.removeIf(tag -> params.oldName.equals(tag)); " +
            "                    tagArray.tags.add(params.newName); " +
            "                  } " +
            "                }";
  }
```

This is the method which uses the `org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.UpdateByQueryRequest` class to send the `Script` with the updates :

```java
  private void submitAsyncUpdate(UpdateByQueryRequest updateByQueryRequest, ActionListener<BulkByScrollResponse> listener) {
    elasticSearchClient.getClient().updateByQueryAsync(
            updateByQueryRequest,
            RequestOptions.DEFAULT,
            listener
    );
  }
```

This is the main method which uses the `Script` constructed by `updateESTags()` and sends a new `UpdateByQueryRequest` with `submitAsyncUpdate()` :

```java
  public void updateCodeName(Code code, String previousCodeName) {
    List<DataSource> esDataSources = catalogClient.getDataSourceByType(DataSourceType.ELASTICSEARCH);
    String[] indices = new String[esDataSources.size()];
    esDataSources.stream().map(DataSource::getName).map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(indices);

    submitAsyncUpdate(
            new UpdateByQueryRequest(indices)
                    .setScript(new Script(
                                    ScriptType.INLINE,
                                    "painless",
                                    updateESTags(),
                                    Collections.emptyMap(),
                                    new HashMap<>(1) {{ put("newName", code.getName()); put("oldName", previousTag); }}
                            )
                    )
                    .setQuery(// This reduces the work load of the script by allowing it to only operate on matching documents.
                            QueryBuilders.nestedQuery(
                                    "MyTags",
                                    QueryBuilders.termsQuery("MyTags.tags", previousTag),
                                    ScoreMode.None
                            )
                    ),
            new LoggingResponseAsyncActionListener(
                    format(
                            "Edit Tag to change \"%s\" to \"%s\" in the MyTags.tags fields.",
                            previousTag,
                            tag.getName()
                    )
            )
    );
  }
```

When I use Kibana to confirm the updates to ES, this sort of query does not return any results :

```
GET /reddit/_search
{
  "_source": ["MyTags.tags"],
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "MyTags",
      "query": {
        "terms": {
          "MyTags.tags": 
            ["UPDATED TAG"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```